# Connection string per user with WCF Services

Tags: wcf, web-services, database-connection, wcf-security

We are developing an ASP.NET MVC application with WCF services. The problem is that we need to integrate the app with the standard security model of the company.

This model uses a different database user and password (connection string) per application user, this connection string is provided when the user is authenticated and should be used for all web services to connect to the database.

We are figuring out what is the best way to pass this connection string to the wcf services. Someone in my team suggest to store this connection in the session and send it to the service in every message, maybe using some WCF extensibility to pass this connection automatically.

Another suggestions?

Comment: What authentication method are you using currently ?

Comment: Forms Authentication and a WCF service that validates the user, this service is the only that uses a fixed database conecction.

Comment: Are you able to implement the solution !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a custom soap header to pass session data around and this approach has been very successful in our production environment. It is pretty straightforward.

Comment: We finished to implement this approach. We've used an EndpointBehaviour to pass the sessiondata (user and password).

Comment: Glad to hear another success story. Moreover, depending on your instance context mode, you can also put that information in the InstanceContext via an extension. Then you can, write some wrapper code to yield: 'var principle = SnahiderSession.Principle;' straight from your service operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **InstanceContextMode.PerSession** in WCF service to share one time created connection instance with all service calls within a session and when you are done you can dispose the connection by calling DisposeConnection() method.

Hope this will help you !

**Example:**

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IConnectionService
 {
     [OperationContract]
     void InitSqlConnection(string UserName, string passWord);

     [OperationContract]
     void DisposeSqlConnection();

     [OperationContract]
     string GetUserAccounts();

     [OperationContract]
     string GetUserRoles();

}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class ConnectionService : IConnectionService
    {

        SqlConnection connection;

        public void InitSqlConnection(string UserName, string passWord)
        {
            if (connection == default(SqlConnection))
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection(string.Format("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WADB;User Id={0};Password={1};", UserName, passWord));
                connection.Open();
            }
        }

        public void DisposeSqlConnection()
        {
            if (connection != default(SqlConnection))
            {
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public string GetUserAccounts()
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            if (connection != default(SqlConnection))
            {
                //// do database operation with "connection"
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblUserAccount", connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                data = ds.GetXml();
            }
            return data;
        }

        public string GetUserRoles()
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            if (connection != default(SqlConnection))
            {
                //// do database operation with "connection"
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblUserRole", connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                data = ds.GetXml();
            }
            return data;
        }
}
```